# Why is a functional dependency described as a "one-to-many" relationship?

Tags: database-theory

As far as I know, the definition of a functional dependency reads that, given the attributes X and Y, "each X value is associated with precisely one Y value". But then the author of the article that I read called this a "one-to-many" relationship. Isn't this really "one-to-one"..?

Comment: They meant 1:many. (Sloppily speaking,) When x->y in a table, the binary relationship that is x subtuple : y subtuple is many:1 and the binary relationship that is y subtuple : x subtuple is 1:many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the FD can't be described as "One-to-one" relationships. In One-to-one relationships, the X value identifies a Y value and **vice-versa**. In FD this **doesn't happen**. In fact, the Y values can be shared from different tuples with the same X value.

Think to a simple table with only cities, states and nations (And don't care about the redundancy). We know that the state identifies one and one nation, but a single nations doesn't identify a single state.

So, **generally  X implies Y but Y doesn't imply X**.

A last observation: an one-to-one relationship need that the tables involved in the relationship **must** have the same number of rows, in order to associate to every a **one** b and to associate to every b **one** a. In the textbook you'll find a lot of FD in which this doesn't happen.

So we can describe a FD as an association of a Y value to many (only sometimes one) X values. So it's called an **one-to-many** relationship.

Comment: Because X is on the left side of the FD relationship, shouldn't it be described as "many-to-one" then, given your explanation..?

Comment: Often I found many-to-one and one-to-many as synonymous in DB theory.  For example, in Relationships in ER model, if the first entity has cardinality (1,1) or (1,N) it is called however "one-to-many relationship"

Answer (score -1):

This example illustrates the concept of functional dependency. The situation modelled is that of college students visiting one or more lectures in each of which they are assigned a teaching assistant (TA). Let's further assume that every student is in some semester and is identified by a unique integer ID.

```
StudentID   Semester    Lecture             TA
1234        6           Numerical Methods   Azhar
1201        4           Numerical Methods   Peter
1234        6           Visual Computing    Ahmed
1201        4           Numerical Methods   Peter
1201        4           Physics II          Simone
```

We notice that whenever two rows in this table feature the same StudentID, they also necessarily have the same Semester values. This basic fact can be expressed by a functional dependency:

```
StudentID → Semester.
```

Other nontrivial functional dependencies can be identified, for example:

```
{StudentID, Lecture} → TA
{StudentID, Lecture} → {TA, Semester}
```

The latter expresses the fact that the set {StudentID, Lecture} is a superkey of the relation.

Comment: From this example, I still don't understand why the functional dependency is called a "one-to-many" relationship. In your example, the StudentID always has only one and the same Semester that corresponds to it. Where's the "many" here..? Same for other dependencies.

Comment: Is this [exact copy paste of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency#Lectures) ?

Comment: The data also suggest a `Semester → StudentID` dependency but I doubt that would appear with actual data.

Comment: Also: this table has 2 identical rows. That makes it a not good example.